# How to convert an arbitrary Java string to a limited set of characters in a reversible manner?

Tags: java, string, character-encoding, etag, information-theory

What's the best way to convert an arbitrary Java String to a limited set of characters and back again?

I would like to generate an ETag from an arbitrary Java String, and then be able to reproduce the original String when that ETag is subsequently presented.

[RFC 7232](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7232#section-2.3) and [RFC 7230](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-3.2.6) between them define the valid characters as:

```
etagc          = %x21 / %x23-7E / obs-text
               ; VCHAR except double quotes, plus obs-text
obs-text       = %x80-FF
```

Loosely, that means any 8 bit character greater than or equal to `0x21`, except `0x22` and `0x7f`.  Given that Java Strings can contain any Unicode character, there are quite a few that aren't permissible in an ETag.

Simplistically, because 0 - 9 and A - F are all valid ETag characters, I could:

1. convert the String to a UTF-8 byte array;
2. then convert each byte to a two-digit hex number;
3. then concatenate the hex numbers to make the ETag.

The code to reverse this is a little painful, but it *is* perfectly reversible, and it works for all Java Strings.

However, my simplistic method produces very long ETags, which is inefficient, and might cause problems in practice.

How can I produce shorter ETags by making use of the fact that there are 220 characters available to me?  Is there a library for this very purpose?

Comment: You're looking for Base64.

Comment: Base64.  Look it up.

Comment: Well... I'm looking for Base220

Comment: Are the strings random, or words from human language? Because if the sequence of characters has low entropy like real words do, compression will be helpful. In any case, you should be able to block the input into 31-byte numbers, and encode those using base-220 digits (yielding a 32-character output block).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a "base 220" encoding/decoding library available that conforms to your spec. (Although, you might want to take a look at [Furcadia Base 220 Encoding](http://dev.furcadia.com/docs/base220.pdf) for encoding fixed-length data blocks.) You can do better than Base 64 with Base 91 (see [here](http://base91.sourceforge.net/) and the updated version at [Github](https://github.com/bwaldvogel/base91)).

If you want to use as much of the 220 characters as possible, you'll have to roll your own. The Base 64 or Base 91 codes are good starting places. (Especially analyzing the differences between them will give you an idea of how to get to 220.) Since you have to deal with arbitrary input length, you shouldn't expect to be able to make full use of 220 characters for encoded data. You'll either need to reserve some characters to signal control, fill, etc. or inject additional data into the encoded stream to indicate string lengths.

Answer (score 0):

If your strings are mostly ASCII, implement a *modified* [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Description) *(variant of, but not to be confused with, [MUTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Modified_UTF-8))*, where the modification is that `0x00` - `0x20`, `0x22`, and `0x7f` are all encoded in 2 bytes.

This works well, because multi-byte UTF-8 sequences only use `0x80` - `0xff`, which are all valid in the ETag, according to the specification you referenced.

*Example:* The Java string `"Test \"\u20AC\""`, which is the text `Test "€"`, would encode as bytes `54 65 73 74 c0 81 c2 81 e2 82 ac c2 81`, which will display in ISO-8859-1 as `TestÀÂâ¬Â` and in Windows-1252 as `TestÀ�Â�â‚¬Â�`.

---

However, using bytes `0x80` - `0xff` in HTTP headers can cause trouble (e.g. see the text display of bytes `81` and `82` above), so it's better to avoid them if possible.

It is possible if you just use the standard [Base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) encoding. You will of course first have to encode your text to bytes. If your strings are mostly ASCII, use UTF-8, otherwise just use the 2-byte `char` values directly, i.e. use [UTF-16](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16#Description).

*Example:* Using same Java string as above, it would encode to `VGVzdCAi4oKsIg==`, which consists of pure valid ASCII characters.

In Java 8, that is easily done:

```
String input = "Test \"\u20AC\""; // 20AC is Euro sign
byte[] utf8Bytes = input.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
String base64Encoded = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(utf8Bytes);
```